# Replace Method Name Dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method, GetData(), which I would like to exchange its name dynamically based on a string parameter.

The first thing was to Get the Method out of the string parameter, MethodName.

```
var methodinfo = repository.GetType().GetMethod("MethodName");
```

Now, how to replace the GetData() method below with the dynamic value that is extracted in methodinfo?

```
var argumentType = repository.GetData().GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

I tried something like this but didn't work:

```
var argumentType =  methodinfo.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I've read your question several times and I honestly don't have the foggiest idea.

Comment: If you are really trying to **change** the name of a method during runtime, forget it. You can't. Let us know what you are trying to do and maybe we can send you in the right direction.

Comment: Please post what you want to achieve, there is probably a better way than dynamically changing method names (which is pretty unusual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right you would need something like this:

```
public class ProgChoice
{
    public static void ProgSelection()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        Type t = assembly.GetType("ProgChoice.ProgSelection", false, true);

        string lcProgStr = "Prog";
        int liProgNumb = 4;

        // Concatenate the 2 strings
        lcProgStr = lcProgStr + liProgNumb.ToString();

        MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod(lcProgStr);
        method.Invoke(null, null);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will mark this as an answer; however, in my case I had to pass repository as an argument to method.Invoke(repository, null). So the end result was: var argumentType = methodinfo.Invoke(repository, null).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];